# Wordpress & IE specific markup error

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, internet-explorer-9

I have this piece of code within a Wordpress loop that gathers all parent terms of the current post and displays children terms of each parent in an unordered list.

```
<?php $taxonomyName = "custom_tax";
$parent_terms = get_terms($taxonomyName, array('parent' => 0, 'orderby' => 'slug', 'hide_empty' => false)); ?>  
<ul>
  <?php foreach ($parent_terms as $pterm) :
    $terms = get_terms($taxonomyName, array('parent' => $pterm->term_id, 'orderby' => 'slug', 'hide_empty' => false));
      foreach ($terms as $term) :?>
          <li><a><?php echo $term->name ?></a></li>
      <?php endforeach;?>
  <?php endforeach;?>
</ul>
```

This works in FF, Chrome, Safari & Opera, however in IE9, I get

```
<ul>
  <a>
  <li>Term1</a></li>
  <a>
  <li>Term2</a></li>
  ...
<ul>
```

I'm sure there is a simple fix, I checked and didn't find any similar issues here or in the WP forum so I'm hoping someone can shed some light on whether this is a known issue.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The HTML code generated by you PHP script isn't affected by the browser you are using.
Using output buffering you should save the generated html into a file, to see what html code you script is generating.

Clear the cache in IE and try it again. Does this help?

Comment: After clearing cache in IE, I get `<ul><a><li>term1</li>...</ul>` Should I uninstall/reinstall IE?  I have 64bit version btw.

Comment: Can you try the output buffering thing, what I suggested?

Comment: When calling the foreach loops from a function with ob_start('custom_tax_query'), I get the same markup as in the op.  I'm very confused.